# QT Creator compile C++ file? Very simple question

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;
}
```

This code works, but it run then close windows immediately. Need a fix :)

Comment: Shouldn't a hello world program exit immediately? :)
You can see the output under "[3] Application Output" still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this getch() or getchar() before return and the consolw window will stay till you enter something

Comment: getch() not works, it said : getch was not declared in this score;
but i can use cin.get(); -> Why?

Comment: `getch` is not a standard C++ function.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Start->Run, type `cmd`, `cd` to the project binary directory, then enter your executable name.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the 'Run in Terminal' Qt Creator project setting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how QT Creators works but you could try.

Add:

```
char x;
cin>>x;
```

You'll have to type a letter and press enter to exit.

Or

```
#include<widows.h>
....
....
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

OR

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
  ....
  ....
  cin.get();
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: system() is declared in stdlib.h

Comment: No, try an example using #include<windows.h> and you'll see it works :)

Comment: cause windows.h includes stdlib.h

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in viewing the output, it is shown in application output section of Qt Creator

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a breakpoint at return 0; and run in debug.